# Rails checking db for already existing user and add comment without creating a new user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a landlord and comment class.
Landlord has 1:N comments.
When a landlord is created it creates a comment on the same form (nested).

When the form is submitted, users_controller#create is called.

I want to check the database if the landlord with the same name, city and state already exists  and add the comment to that landlord instead of creating a new one.

```
def create      
#check if a landlord of the same name already exists and add comments to that


    if Landlord.find_by_name(params[:name]) && Landlord.find_by_city(params[:city])&& Landlord.find_by_province(params[:province])
     @landlord_exists = Landlord.find_by_name(params[:name]) && Landlord.find_by_city(params[:city])&& Landlord.find_by_province(params[:province])

     @landlord_exists.comments.build

     @landlord_exists.comments[0].setIP request.remote_ip

     @landlord_exists.save
    else 
      @landlord = Landlord.new(params[:landlord])
      @landlord.comments[0].setIP request.remote_ip
      if @landlord.save

       flash[:success] = "Thank you for submitting a Landlord"
       redirect_to landlords_path
      else

      end
    end
end
```

update # 1 down to

```
  def create    

    @landlord = Landlord.where(:name => params[:name], :city => params[:city], :province => params[:province]).first_or_create!

    @landlord.comments[0].setIP request.remote_ip


    if @landlord.save     
      redirect_to landlords_path
    else
    end

  end
```

The line

```
@landlord = Landlord.where(:name => params[:name], :city => params[:city], :province => params[:province]).first_or_create!
```

Seems to be returning a nil object  thus throwing errors when setIP is called.
What would be causing this? I have tried it in the terminal and it worked fine although I was using hardcoded values.

Comment: So, what's your question? Is your code not working? What errors is it throwing off?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it would be to use ActiveRecord::Relation's `first_or_create!` method. This will perform a query based on the params entered in the form, and create a record if no matches are found, meaning you can get of the `if ... else` conditionals:

```
@landlord = Landlord.where(params[:landlord]).first_or_create!
@landlord.comments.build
# etc ...
```

Comment: I've been trying    @landlord = Landlord.where(:name => params[:name], :city => params[:city], :province => params[:province]).first_or_create! But when I attempt @landlord.comments[0].setIP request.remote_ip I am receiving a nil class error on method call setIP.